# related_name in many to many field

Tags: django, django-models

Below is my code.

```py
class Thing(models.Model) :
    title = models.CharField(
            max_length=200,
            validators=[MinLengthValidator(2, "Title must be greater than 2 characters")]
    )
    text = models.TextField()
    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
            related_name='fav_thing_owner')
    favorites = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        through='Fav', related_name='favorite_things')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    # Shows up in the admin list
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Fav(models.Model) :

    thing = models.ForeignKey(Thing, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='favs_users')

    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/options/#unique-together
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('thing', 'user')

    def __str__(self) :
        return '%s likes %s'%(self.user.username, self.thing.title[:10])
```

But I got confused related_name in ManytoMayFied.

for example, in my code I can get user's Thing(my model name) using user.fav_thing_owner.

But in ManyToManyField, I have two related_name(favorite_things, favs_users).

user.favorite_things and user.favs_users get same object..?

Comment: No, `user.favorite_thing` will get you a queryset of `Thing` objects, whereas `user.favs_user` will get you a queryset of related `Fav` objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `user.favorite_things` and `user.favs_users` get same object..?

**No**, `user.favorite_thing.all()` will get you a queryset of `Thing` objects, whereas `user.favs_user.all()` will get you a queryset of related `Fav` objects.

The `Fav` objects that you get with `user.favs_user.all()` will thus point to the `Thing` objects that you get by `user.favorite_thing.all()`. If your `Fav` objects contains more data, for example the timestamp when you made that `Thing` your favorite, it thus can be sometimes useful to fetch the `Fav` objects instead and then thus enumerate over the `.thing`s that these `Fav` objects refer to.

The `related_name=…`s look a bit odd. Typically it is the name to fetch the relation in reverse. Perhaps it is better to rename the `favs_user` to `favorites` or something.